# How solve this question

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sum of the first $n$ terms of two Arithmetic Progressions are in the ratio $\frac{2n + 31}{5n –3}$ ,which terms of the sequence are equal ?How to solve this problem in general.

I have no clue what to begin with, a hint would suffice.

Comment: The sum of the first $n$ of first and second A.P

Comment: @RossMillikan, thank you! I just realized after re-reading the question (seems I read too quick) :)

Comment: Is the given relationship always true? for all values of $n$ or only some fixed $n$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the progressions are
$an+b$ and $cn+d$.
The sum of the first $n$ terms
(I will start at $1$) is
$\sum_{k=1}^n (ak+b)
=a \sum_{k=1}^n k + nb
=an(n+1)/2+nb
=n(a(n+1)/2+b)
$.
Similarly,
the sum for the second is
$n(c(n+1)/2+d)$.

Therefore,
cancelling the $n$,
$\frac{2n + 31}{5n –3}
=\frac{a(n+1)/2+b}{c(n+1)/2+d}
=\frac{a(n+1)+2b}{c(n+1)+2d}
=\frac{an+2b+a}{cn+2d+c}
$.

This give
$a=2$, $2b+a=31$, $c=5$, and $2d+c=-3$,
so
$b=(31-2)/2 = 29/2$
and
$d = (-3-5)/2 = -4$.

The terms (of the two sequences)
are equal when
$an+b = cn+d$
or
$n = \frac{d-b}{a-c}
=\frac{-4-29/2}{2-(-3)}
=\frac{-37/2}{5}
=\frac{-37}{10}
$.

Since this is not an integer, 
no corresponding terms are ever equal.

This is,
of course,
modulo errors or misunderstandings on my part.
Since I have
(I think)
determined the two sequences,
you can then answer
any questions you want about them.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem we need to understand exactly what an arithmetic progression is:

Both the progressions take on the form of:

$$Q_0, Q_0 + r, Q_0 + 2r ... Q_0 + nr$$

Where $Q_0$ is the initial value and the value of R is the constant difference between each difference.

That being said we can layout our two series as

$$A_0, A_0 + r_1, A_0 + 2r_1 ... A_0 + (n-1)r_1$$

$$B_0 + B_0 + r_2, B_0 + 2r_2 ... B_0 + (n-1)r_2$$

Now to compute the sum of the first $n$ terms of the first series observe that there are n copies of $A_0$ and therefore the sum is

$$(A_0 + (A_0 + r_1) ... (A_0 + (n-1)r_1) = n(A_0) +  r_1 + 2r_1 ... (n-1)r_1$$

This of course can be simplified to:

$$n(A_0) + r_1 (1 + 2 + ... (n-1)) = n(A_0) + r_1 \frac{(n-1)n}{2} = n \frac{A_0 + r_1n - r_1}{2}$$

The corresponding formula for the second series is:

$$n \frac{B_0 + r_2n - r_2}{2}$$

Now we are informed that ratio of these sums has a closed form and in general

$$ \frac{n \frac{A_0 + r_1n - r_1}{2}}{n \frac{B_0 + r_2n - r_2}{2}} = \frac{2n+31}{5n-3} $$

We simplify this to:

$$ \frac{{A_0 + r_1n - r_1}}{ {B_0 + r_2n - r_2}} = \frac{2n+31}{5n-3} $$

Cross multiplying

$$ (A_0 + r_1n - r_1)(5n-3) = (2n+31)(B_0 + r_2n - r_2) $$

At this point we solve for $A_0$ in terms of the other constants which will require expanding products, and grouping all the terms involving $A_0$ together and solving it as a linear equation.

$$A_0 = \frac{(2n+31)(B_0 + r_2n - r_2)}{5n-3}- r_1n + r_1$$
Once that is done however:

We now are attempting to find solutions to the equation

$$B_0 + k_1r_2 = A_0 + k_2r_1$$

That is we want to find points that the series have in common. Of course we can substitute our expression for $A_0$ into here:

$$B_0 + k_1r_2 = \frac{(2n+31)(B_0 + r_2n - r_2)}{5n-3}- r_1n + r_1 + k_2r_1$$

and we have now obtained ourselves an expression for the points the series have in common. Except there is one critical point: $k_1, k_2, n$ must all be integers.

The trick at this stage is (and I assume at this point you are given a value $n$ to work with) is to find solutions to the problem

$$L \equiv B_0 \mod r_2$$
$$L \equiv \frac{(2n+31)(B_0 + r_2n - r_2)}{5n-3}- r_1n + r_1 \mod r_1$$

Solutions to this system of congruences (whose solution can be generated by the chinese remainder theorem) are values $L$ that arise from integer pair solutions $k_1, k_2$ to:

$$B_0 + k_1r_2 = \frac{(2n+31)(B_0 + r_2n - r_2)}{5n-3}- r_1n + r_1 + k_2r_1$$

Note there will not always be a solution! But when there does exist a solution this is a method to generate it. If we assume there are solutions $L$ they can be formed by noting

$$ B_0 + k_1r_2 \equiv \frac{(2n+31)(B_0 + r_2n - r_2)}{5n-3}- r_1n + r_1 \mod r_1$$

And therefore

$$ k_1 \equiv \frac{\frac{(2n+31)(B_0 + r_2n - r_2)}{5n-3}- r_1n + r_1 - B_0}{r_2} \mod r_1$$

And therefore

$$ k_1 = \lbrace \frac{\frac{(2n+31)(B_0 + r_2n - r_2)}{5n-3}- r_1n + r_1 - B_0}{r_2} \mod r_1 \rbrace + tr_2$$

for integers $t$.

Answer (score 0):

You are expected to assume this is true for all $n$.  Because everything scales, we can let one series be defined by first term $1$ and difference $d$, the second by $b,e$  Now write down what you know for $n=1,2,3$ You get three equations in three unknowns.

Comment: why should the first term be $1$ of first series?

Comment: Its a bit over kill,isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: @Seeker Really?  But didn't you write "I have no clue what to begin with, a hint would suffice"?